# How to get emacs to automatically load and save desktop from initial directory?

Tags: emacs

I usually have 3-4 different projects that I work on at once. So I am trying to figure out how to get emacs to load the desktop from the folder that I open emacs from and also save to that file when I exit from that emacs instance.

All of the docs I have seen either describe how to get emacs to automatically open and save from a default location (which makes multiple desktops impossible), or to manually load and save the desktop to a specific directory (which I am doing now).

Thanks!

Comment: You can manually load and save desktop by `(desktop-read DIRNAME)` and `(desktop-save DIRNAME)`. You should bind `DIRNAME` to your folder names in each case.

Comment: Artscan: I am currently running M-x desktop-change-dir and M-x desktop-save when I open and close emacs but I am trying to find a way to automate this. Are you suggesting I do some lisp in my init.el? If so could you give me some more details? I am totally uninitiated with that stuff. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can't do it without elisp. See my answer.

Comment: It's better to use desktop+, as @Francesco mentioned, and you can do it without elisp. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this to your .emacs:

```
(setq your-own-path default-directory)
(if (file-exists-p
     (concat your-own-path ".emacs.desktop"))
    (desktop-read your-own-path))

(add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
      `(lambda ()
        (desktop-save ,your-own-path t)))
```

Upd.: v. 2, ignore on demand.

```
(setq your-own-path default-directory)
(if (file-exists-p
     (concat your-own-path ".emacs.desktop"))
    (if (y-or-n-p "Read .emacs.desktop and add hook?")
    (progn
      (desktop-read your-own-path)
      (add-hook 'kill-emacs-hook
            `(lambda ()
               (desktop-save ,your-own-path t))))))
```

Comment: Did you consider using the `default-directory` variable instead of shelling out to `pwd`?

Comment: Now it's buggy :) when your anonymous function executes, it will evaluate `default-directory` for whatever the current buffer is. You might modify it thus: `\`(lambda () (desktop-save ,default-directory))`

Comment: You also need to supply the `RELEASE` argument to avoid leaving a lock file; so actually: `\`(lambda () (desktop-save ,default-directory t))`

Comment: Yes, I didn't check it. :)

Comment: This is the perfect solution for me and answers my question exactly.

An now that I've tried it I wonder if it's possible to add a yes/no confirmation on startup to avoid loading the file? Then both the startup and shutdown hooks would be ignored if I answered no to this question on startup. Thanks, this is helping me learn some init code!

Comment: Two problems: 1) The code tries to save the desktop file in whatever default directory the editor is currently in. Is it possible to store that file path used to load the desktop file and then be sure to save the session to the same file. Otherwise if you dired into a sub dir and exit it saves another desktop there. 2) This code is still leaving a lock file for me. Maybe the RELEASE argument is wrong?

Comment: 1) You should use your own variable instead of `default-directory` to control file path. 2) `desktop-save` with RELEASE argument tries to remove the lock file for the desktop in `default-directory` now. So, if you fix 1) then 2) should work correctly.

Comment: I fixed answer. Variable `your-own-path` stores the value of `default-directory` when emacs instance is created.

Answer (score 3):

I have developed a small set of functions to manage multiple desktops: [desktop+](https://github.com/ffevotte/desktop-plus)

You might want to check it out. My workflow is not exactly the same as yours, though:

1. I always run emacs from the same directory (I run it from a key binding in my window manager), meaning that I can not rely on the starting directory to know which desktop I want to work with
2. the first time I work on a new project, I call <kbd>M-x</kbd>`desktop-create` and provide a name. The desktop is then saved to a central location (under "~/.emacs.d/desktops" by default)
3. each subsequent time I want to work with a saved desktop, I run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`desktop-load`, and am provided with a list of saved sessions in which I can quickly retrieve the name of the desired session.

Sessions are always saved when emacs exits or you load another session.

Comment: How do you update the session after each time you work on it? Run desktop-create again?

Comment: The desktop is automatically saved when necessary by setting `(setq desktop-save t)`

Comment: A little feedback, I am totally loving desktop+, and am using it for all of my projects now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

For a really simple answer I put this at the end of my .emacs file.  It works fine if you save the desktop in the project folder and start emacs from the project folder.

```html
(desktop-change-dir default-directory)
```